# How to calculate the of the age of the universe using astropy?

Tags: astropy

I want to convert the value of Hubble constant H0 into Gyr unit and also want to calculate the age of the universe, t0, by python. The code that I have used is shown below. The conversion of H0 looks fine but the value of t0 should appear 13.78 but it shows 0.013. But if I perform the calculation of t0 analytically then I easily find 13.7. Why it is happening? Expecting your help.

```
import numpy as np

Om=0.3
Ol=0.7
H0 = 72  #km/s/Mpc
from astropy.cosmology import WMAP9 as cosmo
from astropy import units
H0 = cosmo.H(0)
H0.value, H0.unit  
print H0.to('Gyr**-1')
H0 = H0.value

# inverse sinh (Ol/Om)^0.5 = 1.2099
t0 = (2./(3.*H0*np.sqrt(Ol))) * 1.2099
print t0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives the naive age of the Universe (ignoring acceleration):

```
from astropy.cosmology import WMAP9 as cosmo
import astropy.units as u
H0 = cosmo.H(0)
t0 = 1.0/H0
t0_Gyr = t0.decompose().to(u.Gyr)
print (t0_Gyr)

<Quantity 14.10548502 Gyr>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Though I have done it successfully after asking this question here.